# Anaconda Availability in China

Tags: anaconda, conda

This might be a dumb question, but I'm an instructor for a data science class teaching students in China from America.  I need a way for them to access Python, since platforms like Binder, Google Colab, and Microsoft Azure Notebooks, are not available in China.

I've tried to contact Anaconda about the availability of their platform in China, but I haven't received any response.

Does anybody know about the availability and accessibility of Anaconda in China? Alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to access Anaconda in China, and they are based on different mirrors provided either by university (like Tsinghua University
) or company (like Alibaba).

A few examples:

(1) https://mirror.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/help/anaconda/

(2) https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/anaconda?spm=a2c6h.13651102.0.0.4f041b11ENrZ4T

Unfortunetly, many of these websites are in Chinese, so I try to include the key steps here:

(1) Create a `.condarc` file in your home directory if it doesn't exist.

(2) Copy and paste the following things into the `.condarc` file.

```
channels:
  - defaults
show_channel_urls: true
default_channels:
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/r
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/msys2
custom_channels:
  conda-forge: https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud
  msys2: https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud
  bioconda: https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud
  menpo: https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud
  pytorch: https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud
  simpleitk: https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud
```

Then it should work. If it doesn't, try other mirrors available from other universities or the one from Alibaba.

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea about  accessibility of Anaconda in China but i guess they use the mulan language instead of Python.